# route not being added

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a search form to work. but when I hit enter it doesn't run any of the js part and just puts `index.php?srch=randomtext` any ideas why it wont call the js?

```
<form name="sr" onsubmit="return GoToSearch();">
   <div class="search-icon">
     <input name="srch" id="srch" placeholder="Search The site" type="text">
   </div>
</form>
```

js

```
function GoToSearch(){
   var srch = jQuery('#srch').val();
   window.location.href='index.php?route=product/search&search='+srch;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event is probably being bubbled up and the default browser action is kicking in. Returning `false` from your function should prevent this.

```js
function GoToSearch(){
  var srch = $('#srch').val();
  window.location = '/index.php?route=product/search&search='+srch;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="sr" onsubmit="return GoToSearch();">
  <div class="search-icon">
    <input name="srch" id="srch" placeholder="Search The site" type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you would'nt need form if you want to submit input using jquery 
just detect the `keyup` code then `GoToSearch` try this :

```js
$(function() {
$("#srch").on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('do search');
        GoToSearch();
    }
});
});
function GoToSearch(){
   var srch = jQuery('#srch').val();
   window.location.href='index.php?route=product/search&search='+srch;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="search-icon">
     <input name="srch" id="srch" placeholder="Search The site" type="text">
   </div>
```